# query selector all elements that are "display: none;"

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have the following query selector but it does not work. Why?

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:not[style*="display: none;"]')
```

I got the following error `is not a valid selector`

It is working correctly without the `:not` but doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

so I guess I'm not using the `:not` correctly

Comment: try `div:not([style*="display: none;"])`

Comment: Think that `not` should have brackets like `not(X)`

Comment: FWIW, these solutions will only work if the style is inline on the element, not set in CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are forgetting the `()`, use like this `:not([...])`

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('div:not([style*="display: none;"])')
console.log(a)
```

```html
<div style="display: none;">a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div style="display: none;">a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div style="display: none;">a</div>
```

**BUT**, my suggestion is to use a `class` that hide the `div` and then use the query looking for that class... Because this selector: `[style*="display: none;]` is too fragile, it wont get elements that have, for example: `style="display: none"`  (without `;`) or `style="display:none;"` (without a space)

Answer (score 3):

`:not` uses parentheses - it's kind of like a function. Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:not([style*="display: none;"])')
```